# Heap vs. Jumble

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

I search for a word to name a directory on my computer to store files that are just a heap of literally anything. Random files downloaded from the Internet, some old documents that I don't remember what they are about, and so on.

Which word is better for this, *heap* or *jumble* (or maybe something different)? Is there any subtle difference between them?

Comment: A heap is an irregularly shaped pile; it may or may not be a jumble. A jumble does not have to be a heap.

Comment: Thanks, so it seems _jumble_ suits better.

Comment: "Miscellaneous" may be a better word, often abbreviated as "misc".

Comment: Is there any good reason to use English for this?  Why not use your native language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the word “miscellaneous,” as that seems appropriate for the content within the folder. “Jumble” implies some kind of nonsensical, random mess, and “heap” implies an unorganized pile. Any of those words could all work, depending on your preferences.

Comment: ... On the other hand, _Misc_ doesn't imply that there is any chaos. Currently I changed it to just _Mess_.